# How do I send a template created using Twilio's content builder with Twilio's Microsoft bot framework channel adapter

Tags: c#, bots, twilio, botframework

I've been able to send a template built with the Whatsapp templates page by sending the exact content of the template's body with Twilio's adapter for Microsoft Bot framework. But this approach doesn't work when I try sending a template built with the Content Template builder page. How do I go about this?

I've been able to send a template built with the Whatsapp templates page by sending the exact content of the template's body with Twilio's adapter for Microsoft Bot framework. I tried the same approach with a template from the Content Template builder and it didn't work